# running portable vim (from a stick) with your own fonts

Tags: windows-xp, gvim

Platform: Windows xp
Vim: Gvim 72 on a stick

Is there a way to run vim from an usb stick, but with your own font you have somewhere in its directory, but which is not installed on a machine (i.e. it is not present in `c:\windows\fonts`) you're running it on?

*All creative ideas welcomed.*

Comment: I agree with jamessan that it belongs on superuser, but for what it's worth, I'd be really interested to hear if this is possible.  I use vim on a stick quite regularly and it would be great to have Envy Code R go with it.

Comment: @Idigas: did you try my little program from below?

Answer (score 1):

the closest thing to your question i have found is this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326(v=VS.85).aspx

i 've written something tiny, compile it and deploy it along your portable gvim. execute it right before you open gvim:

```
// build: cl.exe /nologo /MT addfont.cpp /link gdi32.lib user32.lib
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int rc = 0;
    if (argc > 0) {
        rc = AddFontResource(argv[1]);
        if (rc > 0) {
            SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    return rc;
}
```

execution like this:

```
 addfont.exe example.ttf
```

the font is available to the system only for the current session, if you reboot the machine the font is away as well (intentional for a portable usb-solution)